# Unittest with Mockito - Ignore method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Im struggeling to learn Mockito to unittest a application. Below is a example of the method im currently trying to test

```
public boolean validateFormula(String formula) {

    boolean validFormula = true;
    double result = 0;

    try {
        result = methodThatCalculatAFormula(formula, 10, 10);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        validFormula = false;
    }

    if (result == 0)
        validFormula = false;
    return validFormula;
}
```

This method calls another method in the same class, `methodThatCalculatAFormula`, which I do not want to call when i unittest `validateFormula`.

To test this, I would like to see how this method behaves depending on what `methodThatCalculatAFormula` returns. Since it returns `false` when `result` is 0, and returns valid if it's any number but 0 I would like to simulate these returnvalues without running the actual `methodThatCalculatAFormula` method.

I have written the following:

```
public class FormlaServiceImplTest {
    @Mock
FormulaService formulaService;

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testValidateFormula() {                 

`//Valid since methodThatCalculatAFormula returns 3`    
when(formulaService.methodThatCalculatAFormula(anyString(),anyDouble(),anyDouble(),anyBoolean())).thenReturn((double)3);        
        assertTrue(formulaService.validateFormula("Valid"));    



//Not valid since methodThatCalculatAFormula returns 0
when(formulaService.methodThatCalculatAFormula(anyString(),anyDouble(),anyDouble(),anyBoolean())).thenReturn((double)0);
    assertFalse(formulaService.validateFormula("Not Valid"));
}
```

However when I run the above code my `assertTrue` is `false`. Im guessing i've done something wrong in my mock setup. How would I test the above method by simulating the return value of `methodThatCalculatAFormula` without actually calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not a mock but a spy (partial mock). You don't want to mock an object, but just one method.

This works:

```
public class FormulaService {
    public boolean validateFormula(String formula) {

        boolean validFormula = true;
        double result = 0;

        try {
            result = methodThatCalculatAFormula(formula, 10, 10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            validFormula = false;
        }

        if (result == 0)
            validFormula = false;
        return validFormula;
    }

    public  double methodThatCalculatAFormula(String formula, int i, int j){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FormulaServiceImplTest {

    FormulaService formulaService;

    @Test
    public void testValidateFormula() {

        formulaService = spy(new FormulaService());
        // Valid since methodThatCalculatAFormula returns 3`
        doReturn((double) 3).when(
                formulaService).methodThatCalculatAFormula(anyString(),
                        anyInt(), anyInt());
        assertTrue(formulaService.validateFormula("Valid"));

        // Not valid since methodThatCalculatAFormula returns 0
        doReturn((double)0).when(
                formulaService).methodThatCalculatAFormula(anyString(),
                        anyInt(), anyInt());
        assertFalse(formulaService.validateFormula("Not Valid"));
    }
}
```

But you should not use spy. You should refactor class into two, so that you can test one against a mock of the other.

Comment: The spy command worked fine. As I understand, it only mocks the specified methods which makes it testable even tho it's a mock.

Comment: Yes, and make sure to use the syntax doReturn(result).when(spy).method() and not when(spy.method()).doReturn(result). The latter one won't work, as it will call the original method before defining the mock method

Comment: Yeah I noticed that since i got a UnfinishedStubbException which I googled and found the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test code in Mocked classes.  If you just Mock it, all of the methods are stubs.

You have to Spy it instead.  Read the Mockito documentation on how to use Spy.